# On publishing sites, how does the user's preferred Display Languages preference affect page contents and CAML query results?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, caml-query, publishing, variations

On an on-premise SharePoint 2016 farm with Language pack deployed, we see that users with different preferred Display Language (in their profile) get different results of CAML queries, different web parts displayed on pages. Looks like there's quite a lot to learn about the intricacies of publishing variations. What are the most comprehensive online resources to read on the topic and what are the recommended practices to managing such sites?